# Set up React Native with remote Mac

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-window

I have a Windows machine and a very old Mac Book. I am trying to set up React Native so I can develop on Windows machine and use the MacBook to build, run the simulator, debug etc. I can't find any official documentation for this particular set up. Is that something has been done before, please?

Any recommendation is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: what you mean by old mac, since you are saying able to build, debug and run in mac. you could develop in mac itself. trying to understand the problem..

Comment: The mac is quite old and my windows machine so trying to do the dev work on the windows and just use the mac as extra machine please

Comment: Check out this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview

Comment: But IMHO it's not very efficient this way. It's faster to run just the simulator on the mac, which points to windows' packager server, and occasionally sync the whole code base to mac for pod updates, release builds, etc..